# Shimano SL-RS47 SIS handlebar shifter reassembly

Tags: shimano, repair, shifter, grip-shifter

How do I reassemble the Shimano SL-RS47-7 SIS left shifter on the handlebar after it became separated after an accident? The shifter became separated and I could only get it into first gear. It does move the derailer but it doesn't have any stops, therefore, springs back to first.

[image]

Comment: Without any indication at all about what the damage is, I don't see how anyone can answer your question. can you include detailed photographs of the damaged shifter?

Comment: Generally, the repair method for a broken/failed Shimano shifter is "buy another one".

Comment: There are several completely different versions of Shimano SIS shifters.  At the very least a picture is needed.

Comment: 'SIS' isn't a model name, it stands for something like 'Shimano Index System'

Comment: Great photo identifying model of shifter. Can you add another of ye whole shifter clearly showing the damage where the halves have become separated?

Comment: impossible to say without a better picture. In general, twist shifters work by having a leaf spring-ratchet attached to one ring, and it engages notches in the other, concentric ring in the grip shifter. If the two pieces aren't pushed together all the way, the spring may not fully seat in the notches because it just rides over them on one side, even a little bit. That would be the good news, because it would mean nothing's completely broken. If the leaf spring/ratchet is broken, it might have the same symptoms  (with the possible addition of a clatter of the broken spring piece.)

Answer (score 1):

Shimano calls this a "REVOSHIFT Shifter (3x8/7-speed)"  and since its the left one, its only a three position shifter.

This model line is called Tourney and is the lowest named groupset.  Its made down to a price and all the design decisions are about being cheaper and faster/easier to assemble.  Downside of this is once its damaged they're generally a write-off.

You could spend ages and still not fix it.   Instead I'd suggest you replace both rotary shifters with an equivalent pod or trigger shifter like the Tourney SL-TX50 left and right.

They will have a thumb lever to drive the chain up to the larger sprocket and a push button that drops the chain to a smaller sprocket.  The left one is 2 or 3 positions, and the right one could be 6 or 7 or 8, so do make sure to get the same number as whatever's on your bike now.

I'd also suggest taking the opportunity to replace the two gear inner cables for a few dollars.   And optionally treat yourself to a new pair of handgrips because the old ones will have to come off anyway.

Left shifter as documented at https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/tourney/SL-TX50-L.html
[image: From https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/tourney/SL-TX50-L.html]